# Can a legendary monster/NPC use a "free object interaction" as part of a legendary action?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, actions, action-economy

By the book (PHB p.190):

> You can also interact with one
> object or feature of the environment for free, during either your move
> or your action. For example, you could open a door during your move as
> you stride toward a foe, or you could draw your weapon as part of the
> same action you use to attack.

And from the Jarlaxle stats block from W:DH (p. 206):

> **Quick Step**: Jarlaxle moves up to his speed without provoking
> opportunity attacks.

The question is: Can Jarlaxle take free action in his legendary action? I'm thinking something like: one of his drow assistants opens his *portable hole* over the gold as an action (swallowing it), the other drow closes the hole (as an action) and Jarlaxle uses his legendary action to take the folded hole and leaves using his legendary action at the end of the last drow turn. Is it possible?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

### No, Because It isn't Jarlaxle's turn

The rules you quoted on PHB p. 190 on free object interactions are in a section entitled "Other Activity On Your Turn." It gives information of things that a character can do on their own turn in addition to their Movement, Action, Bonus Action and/or Reaction.

However, legendary actions are defined as such (MM, p. 11, bold added):

> A legendary creature can take a certain number of special actions -called legendary actions -**outside its turn**.

As such, **the rules on interacting with one object for free during your move (or action) does not explicitly apply to a Legendary action**.

Now it's worth noting that just because something is in the section on "Other Activity On Your Turn" doesn't automatically mean you *can't* do it *outside* of your turn. For example, that section mentions speaking in "brief utterances," and many groups allow characters to shout brief encouragement or advice when it is not that character's turn. However, this particular example could have pretty large impacts on the action economy. If you don't want your players (rightly) expecting to be able to draw a weapon as part of an opportunity attack, it's probably best to conclude that a creature can't interact with an object as part of a legendary action (unless that legendary action specifically allows it).

Comment: Instead of granting movement, if the Legendary action stated that Jarlaxle is granted a Move action, could he then take a free interaction?

Comment: @retriever123 I’m not sure what you mean by “a Move action.”

Answer (score 7):

#### The "free object interaction" rule is written to apply to "your turn".

In the section ["Other Activity on Your Turn"](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#OtherActivityonYourTurn), we see this rule:

> You can also interact with one object or feature of the environment for free, during either your move or your action.

This rule specifically applies to "your turn", as denoted by the section header.

So *rules as written*, the only thing Jarlaxle can do when using his Quick Step legendary action is:

> Jarlaxle moves up to his speed without provoking opportunity attacks.

Since it is not Jarlaxle's turn when he takes a legendary action, the "free object interaction" is not available at that time.